# How to use Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I just installed Ubuntu Mobile on my nexus 4 and cant seem to figure out two things, first where are the settings? How do I access the system settings?

And two, how do I download apps? I don't see an app store anywhere?

Comment: it doesn't have any app store. It is developer preview not intended for daily use. [Read more](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/ubuntu-touch-developer-preview-coming-tomorrow-heres-why-you-shouldnt-get-too-excited) & see [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes#Device_Specific_Issues)

Answer (score 0):

As i know from Joey at OMGUbuntu.co.uk that ubuntu mobile still in development... it's still preview and it's not the final version to public (notyet). So there is no much app or app store, So be patient pls :), the time will come soon XD

Comment: I flashed it about 2 hours ago... and i am absolutely loving it.. although there is almost no functionality and i cant add contacts.. the sms are not working for me.. i CAN make and receive phone calls... so thats good.. but the general ui and the way it flows and works and stuff is just incredible.. so although i know that its not meant for daily use and stuff... since i can make and receive phone calls and access my email via the web app... i will use it as a daily phone and just keep installing the updates... id love to see how this progresses and help out anywhere i can...

Answer (score 0):

The Developer Preview comes with the following functioning applications: Gallery, Phone (Dialer, SMS, Address Book), Camera, Browser, Media Player and Notepad. Everything else is just place-holder information. The setting page and app store hasn't been implemented yet. Even something that is relatively simple such as changing the time zone requires you to ssh into a command line.

Comment: ya.. i have been looking at the documentation that Web-E posted... and ive figured out a bunch of stuff.. im in the process of trying to import my contacts into it.. but since everything was all android/google i am now trying to figure out how to export my google contacts in a way that the  manage-address-books.py create can use.. so far no luck